# ASP.Net 5 not an option for new project in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I upgraded to VS2015 and installed asp.net5 per the instructions on the asp.net website. I do not see an option for using asp.net5 in a new web application. The dropdown only has up to 4.6 and the click thru to more frameworks brings you to the asp.net webpage which also only has frameworks thru 4.6. How do I create an asp.net5 MVC6 project in VS2015?

Comment: See [here](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/first-web-api.html) or [here](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/tutorials/mvc-with-entity-framework.html) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing .NET versions with versions of ASP.NET.

4.6 is a .NET Framework version, ASP.NET 5 is the latest version of the ASP.NET platform, but it can target many different versions of the .NET Framework, including 4.6.

To create an ASP.NET MVC 6 project, open Visual Studio, click on 'File' and 'New Project'. Locate the 'ASP.NET Web Application' Template, select the name, location and if you want it added to source control, then click 'OK'.

When you click 'OK', a new dialog box will appear where you select which web template you want to use.  Find the ASP.NET 5 templates, and select 'Web Application' for an MVC project.  This will create an MVC 6 project.

Comment: You are correct, I was making the improper assumption that asp.net5 was targeting a new .net5 version

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't see any ASP.NET 5 Template in Visual Studio 2015, then probably you:

1. Have not yet install ASP.NET 5.
2. You did installed, but you did it before installing Visual Studio 2015 (Community). In case you did this, then reinstall ASP.NET 5. (This was my case and that's how I ended up here)

Here's the link for [AspNet5](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=627627)